# Program that finds odd numbers product and even numbers amount

Tags: c++

```
//task: to write a program which in the interval from n to m would find 
//odd numbers product and even numbers amount.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, m; //numbers
int k; //loop's variable
int r; //product
int s=0; //sum
cout<<"Write two numbers - "<<endl;
cout<<"The first number: "<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"The second number: "<<endl;
cin>>m;
if (n>m)
swap(n,m);
r=1;
for (k=n; k<=m; k+=1)
    {
        if (k%2==0) //even
        s+=k;

        else // odd
        r*=k;
    }

cout <<"s = "<<s<<endl;
cout<<"r = "<<r<<endl;

}


return 0;
}
```

This code works now!

The task is: Let say the n =1, m=10 The even numbers would be 2,4,6,8,10 and its amount would be =30. The odd numbers would be 1,3,5,7,9 and its product would be = 945. So I need that in the screen would be shown the amount (30) and product (945).

Comment: What does "not the way I need" mean? What output does this code produce and how does it differ from the expected/desired outcome?

Comment: What's with that odd hanging bracket after the for loop?

Comment: @ZachStark: it is the start of a block of code that is executed when the `for` loop completes.  It is probably mean to be in the `for` loop, but it is legal C as written.

Comment: `r=1;` `r*=1;` - Won't that always be 1?

Comment: Are you needing the product of the odd numbers, and the sum of the even numbers? Since you never change `n` or `m` in the loop, either the loop will never exit (`n == m`) or the loop will run until you get bored or the computer crashes or you interrupt the program.  You likely need to set `s = 0;` and `r = 1;` and then use a loop `for (i = n; i < m; i++)` and then inside the loop, if `i` is odd, multiply `r` by `i` and if it is even add `i` to `s`.  After the loop, you can print the values of `n`, `m`, `r`, and `s` appropriately annotated.

Comment: The output is:

"
Write two numbers -
The first number:
(lets say) 1
The second number:
(lets say) 10
(and then it starts writing numbers n times)
...
s2130570112
s2130570112
r1
s2130570113
s2130570113

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to count the number of even numbers, and multiply all of the odd numbers?

Comment: If that's not what you need, you'll have to explain better. The output you're showing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Tawnos, the task is:

Let say the n =1, m=10

The even numbers would be 2,4,6,8,10 and its amount would be =30.
The odd numbers would be 1,3,5,7,9 and its product would be = 945.

So I need that in the screen would be shown the amount (30) and product (945).

Comment: That was what my first iteration of code showed, I'll edit it back and you can take a look

Answer (score 1):

Loop over all numbers (from n->m), determine if each number is even or odd, sum the evens, multiply the odds:

```
    for (k=n; k<=m; k+=1)
    {
        if (n%2==0) //even
            s+=k;
        else // odd
            r*=k;
    }

    cout <<"s"<<s<<endl;
    cout<<"r"<<r<<endl;
```

Here's how I would do the full program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int firstNumber, secondNumber; //numbers
    cout << "Write two numbers - " << endl;
    cout << "The first number: " << endl;
    cin >> firstNumber;
    cout << "The second number: " << endl;
    cin >> secondNumber;

    if (firstNumber > secondNumber)
    {
        swap(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) //even
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        else // odd
        {
            product *= i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Product" << product << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't they want the `cout`s outside the `for` to just get one set per n, m combination?

Comment: ebyrob: I have no idea. I'm trying to decode what ReS really wants, and am at least pointing him at figuring out if the numbers are even or odd.

Comment: This looks like an attempt at homework without fully grasping the concepts. The fact that the variables are all given nonsense names and are declared up front makes me think that, even if this is what he wants, there's a lot more left to learn. However, this isn't codereview, so I'm not code reviewing so much as trying to  problem-solve.

Comment: Yes, more than likely what's expected is to combine s and r into a single number and report that...  Who knows how though.

Comment: @Tawnos, the code does the same thing. I mean it does not work properly. And yes it is a task from one book that my teacher gave me.

Comment: What code does the same thing? Yours? Because yours ends the for loop before the second check, doesn't look like it actually checks for even or odd, and always multiplies your product times 1, so the product will never change.

Comment: @Tawnos, look, I have edited my code how You said. And I wrote the output. As You see, it helped someday, but still it is not what I need.

Comment: You don't need that outer `while (n<m)` loop, you need to swap n & m the other way (I used your loop construct), and you need to initialize `s` to `int s=0;`

Try using better variable names, it will help

Comment: Thanks, @Tawnos! It does work now after I deleted while (n<m).
Could I give You one more question? Could You tell me where I can find the best info about programming in C++ in English? I am just beginner and am senior in high school. I will need to take an exam in a half of year of programming in C++ and Microsoft Office programs( Word and Excel) in order to pass entrance in the university.

Comment: Sure, just don't forget to accept this answer ;). I learned a lot of my C++ from the book "C++ Primer" by Stanley Lippman: http://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Edition-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0321714113 You can also get a lot of help here and on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for learning how to better format and design your code. It's important to clearly ask your questions and specify not only what you want, but what you've tried and why that doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: Click the little check box by my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`int s;` **===>** `int s=0;`

`if (n%k==0)` **===>** `if (k%2==0)`

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, m; //numbers
int k; //loop's variable
int r; //product
int s=0; //sum
cout<<"Write two numbers - "<<endl;
cout<<"The first number: "<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"The second number: "<<endl;
cin>>m;
if (n>m)
swap(n,m);
r=1;


    for (k=n; k<=m; k+=1)
    {
        if (k%2==0) //even
           s+=k;
        else // odd
           r*=k;
    }

    cout <<"s"<<s<<endl;
    cout<<"r"<<r<<endl;
```

Comment: the output with this is like so:

...
s71760

r951059649

s71780

r1103203441

s71800

....